# How to not process when query is outside the raster extent ? (Error when Completely Outside)

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, bash

Given a West North East South bounding box, I want to crop this data from a hundreds of inputXX.tif. Nearly every times but once, the query first print out that it *"falls completely outside raster extent but is going on [processing it] however"*, then uselessly start to process the out-of-range raster, spenting huge amoint of time on EACH file.

```
$gdal_translate -projwin 0 55 -10 45 ./data/input${i}.tif ./tmp/crop.${i}.tmp.tif
Input file size is 6001, 6001
Computed -srcwin 296400 -57000 38400 39000 from projected window.
Warning: Computed -srcwin 296400 -57000 38400 39000 falls completely outside raster extent. Going on however.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

As I'am processing SRTM3's 871 files via a makefile-bash loop...

```bash
#!bash
files=(`ls ../data/cgiar-csi_90/ | grep .tif$`) 
for i in "${!files[@]}"
do
    gdal_translate -projwin $WEST $NORTH $EAST $SOUTH ../data/cgiar-csi_90/${files[${i}]} ./tmp/crop.${i}.tmp.tif 
done 
gdal_merge.py -o ./crop_xl.tmp.tif ./tmp/crop.*.tmp.tif -n -32768
```

**...How to NOT process such raster when query is outside the raster extent ?** and pass without error.

Note: [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) doesn t seems to have native way to jump over such out-of-range inputs, as far as i understand.

Comment: This is only really an issue if you are automating your process to iterate over multiple rasters.  If you are not, then simply check the extent of the raster first (using gdalinfo).  If you are automating the process, please edit your question to state which language/libraries you intend to use (though basically you just need to do a similar check in your iteration loop).

Comment: I'am iterating upon SRTM3's 871 files via a makefile :D Bash prefered, Python ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the option `-eco` from [gdal_translate manual](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html). I throw a **non-blocking error**.

**-epo:** (Error when Partially Outside)
(GDAL >= 1.10) If this option is set, -srcwin or -projwin values that falls partially outside the source raster extent will be considered as an error. The default behaviour starting with GDAL 1.10 is to accept such requests, when they were considered as an error before.

**-eco:** (Error when Completely Outside)
(GDAL >= 1.10) Same as -epo, except that the criterion for erroring out is when the request falls completely outside the source raster extent.